# Dynamically generated grid lines and div's with a range slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I'm trying to make the range slider in my Etch-a-Sketch project work, so that its value (i.e 8x8 - 64x64 = grid size) corresponds with the total number of div's inside my grid-container (.square). The value gets logged into the console, but I can't figure out how to change the total number of squares dynamically according to the sliders value. If I hardcode the value in makeRows(), the grid(lines) show up properly.

I think I'm doing something wrong with scoping and/or passing the correct parameters..? Can anyone give me a hand please?

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Mein-Hirsch/pen/abKLzrV

```
const gridContainer = document.getElementById("grid-container");
// const colors = ["#e74c3c", "#8e44ad", "#3498db", "#e67e22", "#2ecc71"];

const range = document.getElementById("range"); //input Id
const rangeValue = document.getElementById("rangeValue");
let strToNum;

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  gridContainer.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  gridContainer.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);
  for (i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    gridContainer.appendChild(cell).className = "square";
  }
}

makeRows(32, 32);

function sliderValue() {
  let strToNum = parseInt(range.value);
  console.log(strToNum);
  return strToNum;
}

range.addEventListener("input", sliderValue);
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOhs1.png)
[JS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gjqk.png)

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call your function with the correct parameters.
You don't have to set a variable, `+x` is the same as `parseInt(x)`.
Also, don't forget to empty the grid before adding the new elements.

```js
const gridContainer = document.getElementById("grid-container");
// const colors = ["#e74c3c", "#8e44ad", "#3498db", "#e67e22", "#2ecc71"];

const range = document.getElementById("range");
const rangeValue = document.getElementById("rangeValue");

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  gridContainer.innerHTML = "";
  gridContainer.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  gridContainer.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);
  for (i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    gridContainer.appendChild(cell).className = "square";
  }
}

makeRows(32, 32);

function sliderValue() {
  makeRows(+range.value, +range.value);
}

range.addEventListener("input", sliderValue);
```

```css
/* Basic sytling-----------------------------> */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #2c2f36;
  color: white;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.main-container {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

/* Settings-Container Styling -------------------------> */
.settings {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#color-picker {
  margin: 1rem 0 2rem 0;
  width: 190.94px;
  height: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="color"]:first-child {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type="color"]:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
}

.settings button {
  width: 190.94px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 0.75rem;
  border-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  background-color: #3c3f46;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.settings button:hover {
  background-color: #494c55;
}

/* Grid Container Styling -------------------------------> */
#grid-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr); */
  box-sizing: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid rgb(224, 219, 219);
}

/* Slider Styling ---------------------------------------> */
.slider {
  width: 190.94px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  background-color: #2c2f36;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #fdfdfd;
}
.slider input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  height: 2px;
  background: #5c606b;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.slider input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ca4d4d;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Footer Styling ------------------------------------------------> */

footer {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.fa-github {
  color: #151516;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 0.6rem;
}

.fa-github:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c536a6bd5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Etchy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Etch a Sketch</h1>
    <main>
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="settings">
            <input id="color-picker" type="color" />
            <button id="color-mode">Color mode</button>
            <button id="rainbow-mode">Rainbow mode</button>
            <button id="eraser">Eraser</button>
            <button id="clear">Reset</button>
            <div class="slider">
            <input type="range" min="8" max="64" value="100" id="range" oninput="rangeValue.innerText = this.value" />
            <p id="rangeValue">32</p>
          </div>
        </div>        
        <div id="grid-container" class="container"></div>
      </div>
    </main>


    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```